# Adding html and css in eclipse

Tags: html, css, eclipse

i am using phone gap to create an app and i already have HTML and CSS coded. My problem is, how do i import the HTML and CSS to eclipse and on which folder. can anyone suggest how to do that ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your `html`, `css` and `javascript` files inside `assets/www` and modify a bit on MainActivity.java (if this is your default). And add that line below.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/[Whatever entry page].html");
```

This is what it looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/[Whatever entry page].html");

}
}
```

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class direction extends DroidGap

{
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // SetContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
       
    }
}

as you see it's almost same as you have suggested, i still have an error DroidGap cannot resolved to a type and

Answer (score 0):

Inside "res" folder in your project. You can create a new folder by right clicking on top of the res folder. Be careful with what you name your folder though. You can get a Android APPT error: invalid resource directory name. I just currently created a new folder colder animations and it wouldn't accept it, so I called it anim.